# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field and mapping issues

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on a location crud application and after adding the jchart api my program is failing to run. The top error that I get is

```
Error creating bean with name 'locationController': 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service';" and "location is not mapped [select type, count(type) from location group by type]
```

I'm working within spring-tool-suite 4 and msysql workbench as the database. I have autowired as much as possible and not sure where the compile error exist.

Suspected LocationController page

```
package com.bthompson.location.controllers;


import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.bthompson.location.entities.Location;
import com.bthompson.location.repository.LocationRepository;
import com.bthompson.location.service.LocationService;
import com.bthompson.location.util.EmailUtil;
import com.bthompson.location.util.ReportUtil;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

@Controller
public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    LocationService service;

    @Autowired
    LocationRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    ServletContext sc;

    @Autowired
    EmailUtil emailUtil;

    @Autowired
    ReportUtil reportUtil;

    @RequestMapping("/showCreate")
    public String showCreate() {
        return "createLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/saveLoc")
    public String saveLocation(@ModelAttribute("location") Location location, ModelMap modelMap) {
        Location locationSaved = service.saveLocation(location);
        String msg = "Location saved with id: "+ locationSaved.getId();
        modelMap.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        emailUtil.sendEmail("javadevbernard@gmail.com", "Location Saved", "This response means that the location save/update was successful");
        return "createLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/displayLocations")
    public String displayLocations(ModelMap modelMap) {

        List<Location> locations = service.getAllLocations();
        modelMap.addAttribute("locations", locations);
        return "displayLocations";
    }

    @RequestMapping("deleteLocation")
    public String deleteLocaation(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap) {
        Location location = service.getLocationById(id);
        service.deleteLocation(location);
        List<Location> locations = service.getAllLocations();
        modelMap.addAttribute("locations", locations);
        return "displayLocations";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showUpdate")
    public String showUpdate(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap) {
        Location location = service.getLocationById(id);
        modelMap.addAttribute("location", location);
        return "updateLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/updateLoc")
    public String updateLocation(@ModelAttribute("location") Location location, ModelMap modelMap) {
        service.updateLocation(location);
        List<Location> locations = service.getAllLocations();
        modelMap.addAttribute("locations", locations);
        return "displayLocations";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/generateReport")
    public String generateReport() {
        String path = sc.getRealPath("/");
        List<Object[]> data = repository.findTypeAndTypeCount();
        reportUtil.generatePieChart(path, data);
        return "report";

    }

}
```

Error in detail

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2019-05-20 17:50:40.065[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m19932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'locationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'locationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'locationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.bthompson.location.repository.LocationRepository.findTypeAndTypeCount()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:626) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:385) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:866) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M2.jar:2.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M2.jar:2.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:404) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M2.jar:2.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M2.jar:2.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1275) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M2.jar:2.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1263) [spring-boot-2.2.0.M2.jar:2.2.0.M2]
    at com.bthompson.location.LocationwebApplication.main(LocationwebApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'locationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'locationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.bthompson.location.repository.LocationRepository.findTypeAndTypeCount()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:626) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:385) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1184) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:623) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'locationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.bthompson.location.repository.LocationRepository.findTypeAndTypeCount()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1184) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:623) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.bthompson.location.repository.LocationRepository.findTypeAndTypeCount()!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:563) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:556) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:558) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:321) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1841) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: location is not mapped [select type, count(type) from location group by type]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: location is not mapped [select type, count(type) from location group by type]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: location is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3695) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3584) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

I expected the info to be converted into an image to be displayed through the application. But I'm getting compiling errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked over my entities .Location file and have yet to see what needs to be added please review my code.

```
package com.bthompson.location.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Location {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String type;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Location [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", code=" + code + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }



}
```

Comment: I figured out what my mistake was. I'm my code I have a sql statement making a call  from a database table but forgot to mention to the program what the table is. So I changed the ( Entity ) to ( Entity ( name ="table name")) which seems to have fixed the issue.